# Should I use American or British English?

Tags: language, localization

I'm working on a few small games, and I was wondering if I should use American or British English for my user interface? I'm not targetting any specific country, and this will probably be the only localization.

Comment: Why not use geolocation to make the decision?  I hate applications that use Americanised English, because I'm English.

Comment: @codeinthehole - doing localisation properly is *hard*, for a small game you don't necessarily have the resources (or time) to do a proper job. So rather than doing a half-baked job, not localising *might* be the correct solution.

Comment: @codeinthehole And you can imagine how often Canadian English is an option...

Comment: @ChrisF .. come on, don't be soft.  Life is hard .. it doesn't mean we should just give up.

Comment: @codeinthehole - I didn't mean it that way :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As much as it pains me to say it (as a Brit), if you're not going to have any localisation go with American spellings. This will be the preferred spellings for the vast majority of users - either as native speakers (Americans far outnumber the British) or as second language speakers (though there are significant number of those who use British English spellings).

The only exception would be if you are going for a "quirky, English vibe" for your game.

Comment: Quite right old chap *monocle*

Comment: +1, but it's not completely true. In central Europe we learn _Oxford/Britisch english_ and for me it's _colour_, while _color_ is just plain wrong :) And we europeans far outnumber the us-americans. (Btw: What about aussies?)

Comment: @kaiser- fair enough. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @kaiser, Canadians use British english as well.

Comment: Also not just spelling but word choice preferences, e.g. brackets vs parentheses, and things like how to write a date and measurement units